# ¿Cómo funciona el mecanismo de un cursor en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, cursor, mysql-cursores, mysql-8.0

Me gustaría entender ***el funcionamiento de los cursores en MySQL***, ya que si bien el concepto parece claro, no logro entender cómo usarlos.

Por eso me gustaría saber cómo usar ***los cursores de MySQL*** a ser posible.

Comment: No es la primera vez que decís "sobre todo porque si deseo aprender para mi futura formación debo darlo todo y por eso necesito esa valiosa información": eso es irrelevante en la pregunta; en realidad deberías mencionar qué entendés vos por cursor (ya que decís que sabés el _qué_ (definición de cursor) y querés aprender el _cómo_ (cómo usarlos)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Los cursores** consiste en programar en base a un dato y varios atributos; el cursor coge lo genérico y lo usa para una tabla, rellena la primera, luego pasa a la segunda; solo puede hacerse en **bucle (IF)**, sin decirle cual es el siguiente.

A la hora de declarar el cursor, hay que declararlos y hay que tener en cuenta que, la tabla al terminar, desaparecerá y **siempre habrá un indicador/apuntador** al dato que está preparado para trabajar con el.

Si en el **SELECT se declaran 3 atributos, OBLIGATORIAMENTE, deben de haber 3 receptores,** si se va a añadir uno adicional, debe declararse tras haber finalizado el proceso y haber recibido los receptores.

La tabla, de momento, es temporal, la primera operación es **"OPEN"**, así el cursor ya está declarado, este se declara en la primera línea de la tabla; esta tabla existe en memoria.

La segunda es un **"FETCH"**, los datos declarados son llevados a la tabla virtual, a las variables receptoras, el puntero se sitúa en la siguiente si hay 3 receptores; ten en cuenta que si hay 3 receptores, hay 3 columnas.

**"MANEJADOR DE ERRORES"** cuando llegue a este, el cursor o puntero va a desaparecer, el manejador es un programa en memoria.

El tercer paso es un **"CLOSE"** que hace que todo automáticamente desaparezca.

Los cursores obligatoriamente tienen que estar declarados dentro de un procedimiento, el cursor se lanza dentro del procedimiento declarado anteriormente.

- ***OPEN :*** Genera la tabla de forma virtual **(en la memoria)** sin almacenarla y posiciona el cursor en el primer dato de la tabla virtual la cual allí ya existe en memoria.
- ***FETCH :*** Los datos implicados son volcados a las variables receptoras teniendo que coincidir números y tipos. Es decir si hay 3 variables receptoras la tabla virtual tiene 3 columnas.
- ***HANDLER :*** Si yo no pongo este operador el procedimiento provoca error.
- ***CLOSE :*** Esto implica que todo lo creado con la tabla se elimina al cerrar toda esa basura.

Para lanzar un cursor debe estar en un procedimiento. En una función no es posible ejecutar dichos cursores.

***Por ejemplo :***

***1.*** Para cada ***proveedor(nombre)*** mostrar los nombres de los artículos que suministra.

```
USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS art $$
CREATE PROCEDURE art()
BEGIN
   DECLARE fin boolean DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE c1_codProv VARCHAR(4);
   DECLARE c1_nomProv VARCHAR(30);
   DECLARE c2_Articulos VARCHAR(20);
   DECLARE cur_proveedor CURSOR FOR SELECT cod_prov,nombre_prov FROM proveedores;
   DECLARE cur_articulos CURSOR FOR SELECT descripcion FROM articulos WHERE 
   cod_prov=c1_codProv;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=true;
   OPEN cur_proveedor;
   FETCH cur_proveedor INTO c1_codProv,c1_nomProv;
   WHILE fin=FALSE DO
        SELECT c1_nomProv;
        OPEN cur_articulos;
        FETCH cur_articulos INTO c2_Articulos;
        WHILE fin=FALSE DO
            SELECT c2_Articulos;
            FETCH cur_articulos INTO c2_Articulos;
        END WHILE; 
        SET fin = FALSE;
        CLOSE cur_Articulos;
        FETCH cur_proveedor INTO c1_codProv,c1_nomProv;
   END WHILE;
   SET fin = FALSE;
   CLOSE cur_proveedor;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Llamamos al cursor con :***

```
call art():
```

***Y nos devolverá :***

---

| c1_nomProv |
| --- |
| Distribuciones Sur |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Suavizante |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Palmerita |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Zanahoria |

| c1_nomProv |
| --- |
| Todomasa SL |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Lejia |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Napolitana |

| c1_nomProv |
| --- |
| La mancha pastelera |

| c1_nomProv |
| --- |
| Romelsa |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Quitamancha |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Pan |

| c1_nomProv |
| --- |
| Gegatur SL |

| c2_Articulos |
| --- |
| Lechuga |

---

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/158)

[<kbd>Mi apunte</kbd>](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O6wFoFvo_bwHQY2ZKLsClBkBF5Eh98oqbnIwFM0emQc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Aquí una versión (ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/285)) con algunos elementos que pueden ser de interés.

Comment: @wchiquito muchas gracias por tu comentario +1 :-)